# proof of Monge theorem in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to proof theorem below

> (Monge) Show a curve on a surface is a line of curvature iff the surface normal along the curve form a developanle surface .

Can some one help me. A hint or strategy of proof is enough. Thanks

Comment: See for the proof on page 93 in Struik's "Lectures on Classical Differential Geometry" (Dover Publications, 2nd ed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** You need a criterion for a ruled surface
$$\mathbf x(u,v) = \boldsymbol\alpha(u) + v\boldsymbol\beta(u)$$
(with $\|\boldsymbol\beta\|=1$, say) to be developable. You should start by proving that this surface has zero Gaussian curvature if and only if $\boldsymbol\alpha'$, $\boldsymbol\beta$, and $\boldsymbol\beta'$ are everywhere linearly dependent. You'll also need to use the definition of a *line of curvature*, of course.